# setting a link_to with default link label/title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I have a model named product. What i wanted to be able to do was write "product.link" in my view to generate a "link_to product.title, product". I know I can't define the "link" method in the Product.rb file (because link_to does not work there), and i don't want to write "link_to product.title, product" every time i need to create a link to the product.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest the ideal way to go about having a minimal simple way of generating links to my products.

I was also wondering if there was a way in rails to set the default label field to show when i write `"link_to product"` instead of what it shows now: `"#<Product:0x105093f20>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a helper method which does the appropriate thing:

```
# products_helper.rb
def product_link(product)
  # Change these to taste
  link_to product.name, product_path(product)
end
```

Now in your view you can call the following in your view:

```
product_link product
```

As for your question about `#` appearing in the links, this is the `link_to` helper calling to_s on the object for the html portion of the link. Use a helper as above to define the default text.

Comment: this works great. is there a way to use these helper methods inside a mailer view? right now it simply says "undefined method" if I use it there

Comment: actually, never mind. I was able to solve that part by adding this to my config/application.rb:
config.to_prepare do
      ActionMailer::Base.helper "application"
    end